# A concise methodology to create a containerized application that utilize cloud services and transient token for API calls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, github-actions, google-secret-manager

I don't believe there're enough great materials or answer on this topic so I'd like a clear answer.

What is the gold standard for hosting microservices with at least a mediocre degree of security when creating a Docker application that requires a cloud "service account credential" to perform most functions properly? (e.g. Gcloud SDK & service_account.json)

The common answer being

1. mount a local volume

Does not work well in the context of Git Ops since it will require the secret to be exposed during runs because a file will be created.

2. OpenSSL encryption & Decryption
   do not like the amount of manual & lack of cloud management of the key, such as KMS.
3. KMS

Couldn't encrypt service account key with KMS because I wouldn't be able to authenticate the service to retrieve the credentials in the first place.

Comment: What's your problem? Where is running your container? What's your security issue?